# Remove posix shared memory when not in use?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Is there any way, linux specific or not, to have posix shared memory segments (obtained with `shm_open()`) removed when no process is using them. i.e. have them reference counted and have the system remove them when the reference becomes 0

A few notes:

- Establishing an atexit handler to remove them doesn't work if the program crashes.
- Currently, the linux specific way, I embed the pid in the segment name, and try to find unused segments by walking /dev/shm in an external program. Which has the drawback of having to periodically clean them up externally in a rather hackish way.
- As the program can run multiple copies, using a well defined name for the segment that the program reuses when it starts up is not feasible.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a system library approach to this rather than doing it by hand?

Comment: You could use gdb to debug your application so it doesn't crash? That alleviates the problem that crashy applications can't clean up behind themselves...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - at lest on Linux, the kernel doesn't contain anything that can do this. It's up to some application to call shm_unlink() at some point to get rid of a shared memory segment.

Answer (score 7):

If there is a point in your program's execution when it is well known, that all processes that need to open the shared memory segment have already done so, you can safely unlink it. Unlinking removes the object from the global namespace but it sill lingers around as long as there is at least one process that keep its file descriptor open. If a crash occurs after that point, the file descriptor is automatically closed and the reference count is decremented. Once no open descriptors to the unlinked shared memory block remain, it is deleted.

This is useful in the following scenario: a process creates a shared memory block, unlinks it and then forks. The child inherits the file descriptor and can use the shared memory block to communicate with the parent. Once both processes terminate, the block is automatically removed as both file descriptors get closed.

While unlinked, the shared memory block is unavailable for other processes to open it. Meanwhile, if one use `shm_open()` with the same name as the unlinked block, a new and completely different shared memory block would be created instead.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way using a system command and the Linux command "fuser" which allow to list the processes which opened a file. This way, you can check if the shared memory file (located in /dev/shm") is still in use and delete it if not. Note that the operations of check / delete / create must be enclosed in a inter-processes critical section using a named mutex or named semaphore or file lock.

```
        std::string shm_file = "/dev/shm/" + service_name + "Shm";
        std::string cmd_line = "if [ -f " + shm_file + " ] ; then if ! fuser -s " + shm_file + " ; then rm -f " + shm_file + " ; else exit 2 ; fi else exit 3 ; fi";
        int res = system(cmd_line.c_str());
        switch (WEXITSTATUS(res)) {
        case 0: _logger.warning ("The shared memory file " + shm_file + " was found orphan and is deleted");         break;
        case 1: _logger.critical("The shared memory file " + shm_file + " was found orphan and cannot be deleted");  break;
        case 2: _logger.trace   ("The shared memory file " + shm_file + " is linked to alive processes");            break;
        case 3: _logger.trace   ("The shared memory file " + shm_file + " is not found");                            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For the shared memory, created using sysV API, it is possible to have such a behaviour. On Linux only. It is not POSIX shared memory, but may work for you.

In the book [The Linux Programming Interface](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593272203.do) one of the possible parameters for shmctl() is described the following way.

> IPC_RMID
>   Mark the shared memory segment and its associated shmid_ds
>   data structure for deletion. If no processes currently have the
>   segment attached, deletion is immediate; otherwise, the segment is
>   removed after all processes have detached from it (i.e., when the
>   value of the shm_nattch field in the shmid_ds data structure falls to
>   0). In some applications, we can make sure that a shared memory
>   segment is tidily cleared away on application termination by marking
>   it for deletion immediately after all processes have attached it to
>   their virtual address space with shmat(). This is analogous to
>   unlinking a file once we’ve opened it. On Linux, if a shared segment
>   has been marked for deletion using IPC_RMID, but has not yet been
>   removed because some process still has it attached, then it is
>   possible for another process to attach that segment. However, this
>   behavior is not portable: most UNIX implementations prevent new
>   attaches to a segment marked for deletion. (SUSv3 is silent on what
>   behavior should occur in this scenario.) A few Linux applications have
>   come to depend on this behavior, which is why Linux has not been
>   changed to match other UNIX implementations.

Comment: But System V IPC are deprecated now. It is not advised to write new programs with this mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the most complicated case:

- You have several processes communicating via shared memory
- They can start and finish at any time, even multiple times. That means there is no master process, nor is there a dedicated "first" process that can initialize the shared memory.
- That means, e.g., there is no point where you can safely unlink the shared memory, so neither [Sergey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485092/214777) nor [Hristo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445202/214777) answers work.

I see two possible solutions and would welcome feedback on them because the internet is horribly silent on this question:

1. Store the pid (or a more specific process identifier if you have one) of the last process that wrote to the shared memory inside the shared memory as a lock. Then you could do sth. like the following pseudo code:

   ```
    int* pshmem = open shared memory()

    while(true) 
        nPid = atomic_read(pshmem)
        if nPid = 0 
           // your shared memory is in a valid state
           break
        else 
           // process nPid holds a lock to your shared memory
           // or it might have crashed while holding the lock
           if process nPid still exists 
             // shared memory is valid
             break
           else 
             // shared memory is corrupt
             // try acquire lock 
             if atomic_compare_exchange(pshmem, nPid, my pid) 
                // we have the lock
                reinitialize shared memory
                atomic_write(pshem, 0) // release lock
             else 
                // somebody else got the lock in the meantime
                // continue loop
   ```

   This verifies that the last writer didn't die while writing. The shared memory is still persisting longer than any of your processes.
2. Use a reader/writer file lock to find out if any process is the first process opening the shared memory object. The first process may then reinitialize the shared memory:

   ```
    // try to get exclusive lock on lockfile
    int fd = open(lockfile, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXLOCK | O_NONBLOCK, ...)
    if fd == -1
        // didn't work, somebody else has it and is initializing shared memory
        // acquire shared lock and wait for it
        fd = open(lockfile, O_RDONLY | O_SHLOCK)
        // open shared memory
    else 
        // we are the first
        // delete shared memory object
        // possibly delete named mutex/semaphore as well

        // create shared memory object (& semaphore)
        // degrade exclusive lock to a shared lock
        flock(fd, LOCK_SH)
   ```

   File locks seem to be the only (?) mechanism on POSIX systems that is cleared up automatically when the process dies. Unfortunately, [the list of caveats to use them is very, very long](http://chris.improbable.org/2010/12/16/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-file-locking/). The algorithm assumes `flock` is supported on the underlying filesystem at least on the local machine. The algorithm doesn't care if the locks are actually visible to other processes on NFS filesystems or not. They only have to be visible for all processes accessing the shared memory object.

   [This solution has been implemented on top of boost.interprocess.](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/pull/132)

Comment: The shared file lock is quite interesting, thanks Sebastian! One question. the example assumes that the file did not exist, which might not be the case. What happens then?

Comment: `open(lockfile, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXLOCK | O_NONBLOCK, ...)` will create the file if it didn't exist but will open it if it already exists.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that if the file already exists, who is the owner of the lock? Wouldn't it imply that every process takes the "else-statement" then?

Comment: I’m still not sure I understand. If the file exists or not does not make a difference here. The only thing that matters is, if somebody has opened it and acquired a lock. I try to open the file and acquire an exclusive lock at the same time (open with EX_LOCK). That will only succeed if the file is not yet open. It will succeed only for the first process which is then responsible for initializing the lock. Then it switches the lock to a shared lock and all other processes can proceed in the if-case.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sebastian! I messed up a little bit in my previous question (I meant the if-case), but still your reply made me understand it better, thanks a lot again for the clarifications!

Comment: @Sebastian If the first process that inits the shared memory terminates, it will release the file lock. After that other processes can get the file lock and re init the shared memory, right? Is there a solution that you know ?

Comment: @tango-1 yes exactly. The file lock is released if the process terminated, even if it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a global counting semaphore to reference count? Wrap the attach and detach calls so that the semaphore is incremented when you attach to the memory and decremented when you detach. Release the segment when a detach reduces the semaphore to zero.

Comment: This has the same implication as removing it in an atexit handler (atexit is fine for my particular use, as there's only on process writing to the shared memory, and that process can remove it). This does not take care of the segments if e.g. the process crashes.

Comment: You could trap the crash signals and decrement the reference count in the signal handler?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if the below works, or feasible. But my try.

Why do not you execute the helper program, which is executed each time your program crashed.

ie:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern  to  /path/to/Myprogram %p
```

Myprogram is executed when process crashes, and probably you can explore further.

see

```
man 5 core.  for more information.
```

Hope this helps to some extend.